# Matlab contour plot smooth colors

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, contour

Could you tell me how to plot in Matlab figure such as below (smooth transition of colors)? Function `countour` allows only to create plot with contour lines which doesn't provide enough information to me.

[image: http://www.advsofteng.com/images/smoothcontour.jpg]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`imagesc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) with the `'jet'` colormap. Here's an example:

```
x = conv2( randn(600), fspecial('gaussian',200,20), 'valid'); %// example 2D smooth data
imagesc(x)
colormap(jet)
colorbar
grid
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That is not a contour plot!

try [`imagesc`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html), [`surf`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html?searchHighlight=surf) and all of their variants:

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/surface-and-mesh-plots-1.html
http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/image-file-operations.html